# Using a class property while calling the base constructor and in helper methods

Tags: c#, class-constructors

I have this snippet of code --

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _dbAccess;
    public UserManager() : 
         base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
    {
        this.UserValidator = new CustomUserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this);
        var provider = new MachineKeyProtectionProvider();
        this.UserTokenProvider = 
                 new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(
                            provider.Create("SomeCoolAuthentication"));

       //DO I REALLY NEED TO DO THIS AGAIN?
       this._dbAccess = new ApplicationDBContext(); 
    }

    public bool myOwnHelperMethod(){
        //is there a way to use the ApplicationDbContext instance that 
        //was initialized in the base constructor here? 
        //Or do i have to create a new instance?
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to write this so that I can instantiate the ApplicationDBContext, use it to call the base constructor, and then use the same instance later in some helper methods? Or do I have to create another instance in the constructor for use in the helper methods.

Comment: @S.Akbari Please explain why you are making that recommendation. This looks like a fine Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @200_success *Is there a better way to write this?*

Comment: @S.Akbari Please take a look at the [Code Review help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Notice anything? Example code is NOT acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

The first would be to use dependency injection. With this approach, you would remove the creation of `ApplicationDbContext` to outside of `UserManager` and pass it in through the constructor. e.g.:

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _dbAccess;

    public UserManager(ApplicationDbContext dbAccess) : 
         base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(dbAccess))
    {
        ...

        this._dbAccess = dbAccess; 
    }

    ...
}
```

The second option I was just about to suggest has been provided by @Juan in his answer, so I won't repeat that here.

Answer (score 4):

Add this property to your `UserManager` class:

```
 private ApplicationDbContext Context
 {
      get { return ((UserStore<ApplicationUser>)this.Store).Context as ApplicationDbContext; }
 }
```

The `UserManager` class exposes a `Store` property. Since you know the types of objects used internally, you can just cast them and consume the `Context` property in your code.

Comment: `Store` is marked `internal`.  Can it be referenced like this?

Comment: @Amy: `UserManager` is inheriting from `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` so internal member should be available.

Comment: @Juan internal members are restricted to the same assembly.  It has nothing to do with inheritance.  I cannot get your code to compile here.

Comment: It's the fact that it's `protected` that should make it work, not `internal`. If it was `internal` only, it would not be accessible outside of the defining assembly.

Comment: Thank you @Juan and @KirkLarkin! I went with the dependency injection approach! Worked perfectly.